# WooCommerce removing wrapping tags from products/categories

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, product

Is it possible to remove tags, such as the `<li>` tags from around the products/categories in WooCommerce? I have tried searching for hooks, and more. Also, I successfully removed the `<ul>` tags from around the product set as well. I would like to spit out all product data in my cell since I am using foundation framework. Is this possible, or do I have to take an alternative route?

Comment: Please share with us which `<li>` tags you are referring to by sharing an image, the code, a page. Please be aware of [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **To change the html structure in Woocommerce**
>
> You should need, most of the time, to make changes in the [available Woocommerce templates](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/master/templates).

First you should read how to [override woocommerce templates via your active theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Now **to change (or remove) the `<li>` tags on products and product category archives**, you need to override [content-product.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.5/templates/content-product.php) and [content-product_cat.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.5/templates/content-product_cat.php) templates file.

Comment: Excellent. I knew how to do above, I just missed the `<li>` tag.